# Can't use the IP or hostname to access gitlab running by docker image

Tags: docker, http, https, gitlab

I've created a gitlab container in docker using following command:

```sh
docker run --detach \
  --publish 8443:443 --publish 8090:80 --publish 8022:22 \
  --hostname gitlab.west.com \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --volume /home/docker_container/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume /home/docker_container/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume /home/docker_container/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  --shm-size 256m \
  docker.io/gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

and the full contents of the gitlab.rb are:

```yaml
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true

external_url "https://gitlab.west.com:8443"

gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 8022

# letsencrypt['enable'] = false
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/home/docker_container/gitlab/config/ssl/gitlab.west.com.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/home/docker_container/gitlab/config/ssl/gitlab.west.com.key"
```

[access error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unVrU.png)

But neither `http://192.168.1.2:8090` nor `https://192.168.1.2:8443` can access.
Especailly when I type `http:192.168.1.2:8090` in address bar, it automatically convert to `http://gitlab.west.com:8090/`. How can I stop this and use IP to access the gitlab? Or how can I make the hostname work? Do I need extra Nginx config and how to config it?

PS: The firewall in CentOS 7 server is not working.

Would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, GItLab only allows one `external_url` and this URL will be redirected to when configured. If you want to use the IP address, you'll have to use the IP as the `external_url` (which may pose additional challenges for SSL/TLS).

Even if you managed to disable the redirect, all links in the UI would use the absolute URL for the configured `external_url`, meaning as soon as you click anywhere, the other URL will be used.

There is currently a [requested feature](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/21319) to allow multiple `external_url` definitions and may be added to a future milestone, but is not currently possible.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry, I'm new here and can't gtive you a like because of lacking reputation.